# How to access files specified by --files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read in `derp.csv` specified by `--files`, but I'm getting path not found. What do?

```
spark2-shell --master yarn --files derp.csv
scala> spark.read.csv("file:///derp.csv")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/derp.csv;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:360)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:348)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:348)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:533)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:412)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: You can't refer to files by the relative path?

Comment: If I'm running spark2-shell from /some/path with file whatever and use `spark2-shell --files whatever`, that won't work, I have to do `spark2-shell --files /some/path/whatever`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--files` adds files to your Spark application that it then can access using [org.apache.spark.SparkFiles](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$) object.

> **get(filename: String): String** Get the absolute path of a file added through SparkContext.addFile().

```
$ cat /tmp/hello.txt
hello world

$ ./bin/spark-shell --files /tmp/hello.txt
...
scala> import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark._

// Use the file name not the path you specified to access it
scala> SparkFiles.get("hello.txt")
res0: String = /private/var/folders/0w/kb0d3rqn4zb9fcc91pxhgn8w0000gn/T/spark-8c6c6b1a-9a63-408b-aec3-87cadbd332be/userFiles-ec82fe16-6460-4509-84d2-dea7eb11365e/hello.txt

scala> spark.read.text(SparkFiles.get("hello.txt")).show
+-----------+
|      value|
+-----------+
|hello world|
+-----------+
```

---

From comments:

> will this work with yarn cluster mode as well if I want to add local files using `--files` option?

Yes. Report back if not.

> How is this different from `addFile` method?

It is not in the end, but `addFile` is part of your code so every time you want to change file(s) to add, you'd have to recompile the code. For PySpark it's not a big deal, but in Scala or Java it is.

I'd always recommend using command-line options since these are the ways to set things for admins and devops (who may not necessarily want to deal with source code in any programming language).